# PDO multiple LIKE causes; how to?

Tags: mysql, arrays, pdo

```
function searchPaste($string, $err=false)
{
global $sql;
$buffer = $err?"SELECT * FROM `pastes` WHERE `exposure` = 'public' AND `title` LIKE ? OR `paste` LIKE ? OR `lang` LIKE ?":"SELECT * FROM `pastes` WHERE `exposure` = 'public' AND `title` LIKE ?";
echo $buffer."<br>";
$buffer = $sql->prepare($buffer);
$buffer->execute(array(sprintf("%%%s%%", $string)));
if(!$buffer->rowCount()>0)
        return 0;
return $buffer->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

As you see in my first query I am matching by multiple cases problem is "?" is only handled once and I'm unsure how I could go about using an array to do this for all causes.

Anyone know what I could do?

Comment: multiple query makes no sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a bind value / param for each placeholder in your query. You're going to have to do away with the ternary I think. You could try something like this...

```
$buffer = "SELECT * FROM `pastes` WHERE `exposure` = 'public' AND `title` LIKE ?";
$paramCount = 1;
if (!$err) {
    $buffer .= '  OR `paste` LIKE ? OR `lang` LIKE ?';
    $paramCount += 2;
}

$stmt = $sql->prepare($buffer);
$stmt->execute(array_fill(0, $paramCount, "%$string%"));
```

Comment: Is their anyway I can select from a col where string is under 175 chars?

Comment: @user2887749 you mean like `WHERE LENGTH(colname) < 175`?

Answer (score -1):

```
function searchPaste($string, $err=false)
{
    global $sql;
    $sql->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `pastes` WHERE `exposure` = 'public' AND (`title` LIKE :search";
    if ($err) {
        $query .= " OR `paste` LIKE :search OR `lang` LIKE :search";
    }
    $query .= ")";
    $stmt = $sql->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array("search" => "%$string%")));
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

finally got the logic and fixed the query.

Comment: PDO doesn't let you re-use parameter names, see [PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) - *"You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name twice in a prepared statement"*. Also, your parameter array is missing its named keys

Comment: I do get the idea but you have an error at ) i'd imagine. I'm going to try the idea above, thank you though. And :search isn't ever defined.

Comment: @user2887749 i fixed some minor typos. still your multiple search query makes no sense, you have to fix its logic yourself.